Asp.Net Core Web Api Keycloak integration
Keycloak get access token without direct access grants
Hello all,
I set up a simple realm  and added a client with below config:
Client authentication: enabled
Authorization : disabled
Authentication flow: Standart
My question is when i make a login request to my-api
enter image description here
it  returns
{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Client not allowed for direct access grants"
}
and if i enable
Direct access grants
then i can get resopnse with bearer token.
Is there a way to get access token without enabling Direct access grant ?
or am i in a wrong direction.
Thanks
